# How to iterate through child element using child element

Tags: python, xml, python-3.7, minidom

I need to enter the elements of a XML file in a default dictionary.
Using first child element as my key, and the other 2 values will be in the list.

I've tried to keep the elements on separate list and then make them pairs, but still no success.

Below is the XML structure

```
<lines>
    <line>
        <lineName>'Line 1'</lineName>
        <lineCode>'5501'</lineCode>
        <machineName>'Line_1'</machineName>
    </line>
    <line>
        <lineName>'Line 2'</lineName>
        <lineCode>'5502'</lineCode>
        <machineName>'Line_2'</machineName>
    </line>
</lines>
```

Here's how I'm retrieving elements

```
item = myxmlcfg.getElementsByTagName('lineName')
```

item is a list with 2 elements

```
item['Line 1', 'Line 2']
```

same will hapen with lineCode and machineName elements

So I need a default dictionary with the output as this

```
lines {'Line 1': ['5501', 'Line_1'], 'Line 2':['5502', 'Line_2']}
```

where `Key` is `lineName` tag, and value is a list with 2 elements whose values are `lineCode` and `machineName`.

Can you suggest me a way to iterate on the xml elements to get an output as above?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with `minidom`, but with `ElementTree` it's a trivial task:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

if __name__ == '__main__':

    xml_raw = '''
    <lines>
        <line>
            <lineName>'Line 1'</lineName>
            <lineCode>'5501'</lineCode>
            <machineName>'Line_1'</machineName>
        </line>
        <line>
            <lineName>'Line 2'</lineName>
            <lineCode>'5502'</lineCode>
            <machineName>'Line_2'</machineName>
        </line>
    </lines>
    '''

    root: ElementTree = ET.fromstring(xml_raw)
    lines = {}
    for line in root.findall('line'):
        name = line.findtext('lineName').strip("'")
        code = line.findtext('lineCode').strip("'")
        machine = line.findtext('machineName').strip("'")
        lines[name] = [code, machine]
    print(lines)
```

output:

```
{'Line 1': ['5501', 'Line_1'], 'Line 2': ['5502', 'Line_2']}
```

Comment: One last questions, since I started to look for ElementTree. To get an specific element from root, for example, my root is Configuration, inside root, the element I should look for is the tag <lines>, how can I iterate in an element like this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `lxml.etree` and `Element.itersiblings()`:

```
from lxml import etree

root=etree.fromstring(xml)
item=root.findall(f'.//lineName')
lines={i.text.strip("'"): [s.text.strip("'") for s in i.itersiblings()] for i in item}
```

Output:

```
{'Line 1': ['5501', 'Line_1'], 'Line 2': ['5502', 'Line_2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<lines>
    <line>
        <lineName>'Line 1'</lineName>
        <lineCode>'5501'</lineCode>
        <machineName>'Line_1'</machineName>
    </line>
    <line>
        <lineName>'Line 2'</lineName>
        <lineCode>'5502'</lineCode>
        <machineName>'Line_2'</machineName>
    </line>
</lines>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
lines = root.findall('.//line')


  data = {
line.find('lineName').text.strip("'"): [line.find('lineCode').text.strip("'"), line.find('machineName').text.strip("'")]
for line in lines}
```

print(data)

output

```
{'Line 1': ['5501', 'Line_1'], 'Line 2': ['5502', 'Line_2']}
```